# How to keep font size in document and table same

Tags: tables, fontsize, acmart

I am writing a paper in acmart (ACM SIGCOMM provided style). In the paper there is few tables. But font inside the tables are of variable size. Sometime they are large sometimes small. Is there any way to force the font size remain fixed in latex table?

I have added a sample code here. You can run it in overleaf.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{multirow}

% Copyright1 %\setcopyright{none} %\setcopyright{acmcopyright} %\setcopyright{acmlicensed} \setcopyright{rightsretained} %\setcopyright{usgov} %\setcopyright{usgovmixed} %\setcopyright{cagov} %\setcopyright{cagovmixed}

% DOI \acmDOI{10.475/123_4}

% ISBN \acmISBN{123-4567-24-567/08/06}

%Conference \acmConference[Conf Short Name]{Conference Full Name}{Month Year}{Venue} \acmYear{1997} \copyrightyear{2016}


\acmArticle{4} \acmPrice{15.00}

% These commands are optional %\acmBooktitle{Transactions of the ACM Woodstock conference} \editor{Jennifer B. Sartor} \editor{Theo D'Hondt} \editor{Wolfgang De Meuter}


\begin{document} \title{Test ACMART for table } \titlenote{Produces the permission block, and   copyright information} \subtitle{Extended Abstract} \subtitlenote{The full version of the author's guide is available as   \texttt{acmart.pdf} document}


\author{Author 1} \authornote{Dr.~Trovato insisted his name be first.} \orcid{1234-5678-9012} \affiliation{%   \institution{X X University}   \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}   \city{Kent}   \state{Ohio}   \postcode{44240} } \email{email@emia.com}



% The default list of authors is too long for headers. \renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Das et al.}


\begin{abstract} This is a sample abstract for testing.   %===========================MAT comparison \begin{table}   \caption{My table}   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ \begin{tabular}{llllll} \hline  &  & Header 1     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}Header\\ 7170\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Agilio \\ Cx\end{tabular} & Header 3    \\ \hline
                                                                                   \multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Static \\ Features\end{tabular}}} & 

\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Long column 1\\ Long column 1\\Long column 1\\Long column 1Long column\\ 1Long column 1\\ \end{tabular}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}col2\end{tabular}    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}All P4v16 data types.\\Bit,varbit, int,\\string, structure, enum.\\But no float\end{tabular}}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}NA\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}NA\end{tabular}     \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \\ \hline

\end{tabular} } \end{table} \end{abstract} \keywords{SDN, Data Plane, Programmable Switch Architecture} \maketitle \bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The size _should_ be the same as in the text. Are you using some font size changes (`\small`, `\large`, etc.) or scaling/resizing the table (with `\scalebox` or `\resizebox` or `\adjustbox`)? If not, please show us a compilable example of your document that shows this behaviour.

Comment: Can you create a small compilable example that shows the problem? Are you using `margintable`? This uses a smaller font size.

Comment: I am not using any kind of scaling or font size change. Just using vanilla table or table* environment provided by acmart

Comment: @Ayamatma Then you'll need to show us a minimal compilable document that reproduces the problem, (not a code fragment) otherwise it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: I have added a sample code in the post. You can run it on Overleaf

Comment: As already [expected by Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478243/how-to-keep-font-size-in-document-and-table-same#comment1207858_478243) you use `resizebox` in order to make you table as wide as the textwidth which is why you have a larger or smaller font size in tables that are scaled using this command.  Apart from that, your example is not compilable as `tabular` is not allowed in the `abstract` environment.

Comment: Your code is broken and I can't edit (insufficient number of modifications), and it's far from minimal. Please post a minimal working example so we can test the reported problem. When formatting, use the **code** button for your code, not the **quote** button.

Comment: Your example produces the error `! Too many }'s.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup` so no output, but you are using `\resizebox{` so naturally the tables get scaled by arbitrary amounts, don't scale tables!!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\showoutput
\begin{document}


main text 

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    table & text
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{caption text}
  \label{tab:zz}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the log shows

```
.....\T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/9 m
...........\T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/9 t
.........\T1/LinuxBiolinumT-TLF/m/n/8 T
```

That is the main text and the table are 9pt LinuxLibertine and the caption is 8pt LinuxBiolinum

The only reason to use a publisher class such as `amsart` is to enforce the publisher's house style rules and take such choices away from the author, so the usual advice would be not to change such style choices. However it would be possible to set the caption in a larger font if you really needed to, but note the table *is* set at the same size as the document body.

The caption setting (defaulting to small here) depends on the journal option, the class uses code such as

```
\if@ACM@journal
  \captionsetup{labelfont={sf, small},
    textfont={sf, small}, margin=\z@}
  \captionsetup[figure]{name={Fig.}}
\else
 .....
```